# Using "AS" keyword in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with course records, and I want to retrieve the ID column from the course table. I have seen some SQL queries using the "AS" keyword, such as:

```
SELECT c.ID AS course_id FROM course c;
```

What is the purpose of using "AS" in this query, and how is it different from the simpler query below?
`SELECT ID FROM course;` What is the purpose of using "AS" in this query, and how is it different from the simpler query below?

I'm new to SQL and trying to understand the best practices for querying databases. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because `course` has no context. Don't forget, you should also be schema qualifying your object names, and 3+ part naming for columns is to be deprecated, so `SELECT dbo.course.ID` would be "doubly" wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)

Comment: Because this is how the SQL language was designed over 30 years ago

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name closer to 50 years ago... from Wiki - "SQL was initially developed at IBM by Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce after learning about the relational model from Edgar F. Codd[12] in the early 1970s."

Comment: Formally, the language says you always have to have a from clause, which is why some products insist on your using `DUAL` as a dummy table if the `SELECT` clause only contains expressions not depending on any column/table values.

Comment: To be fair through: it could have been `c.id course_ID` without `as` as well.  many SQL iterations allow the optional inclusion of "AS" as to the purpose: in addition to supporting  conxtually aware values, it also allows you to rename an object for future use perhaps adding clarity.  Databases could have table/field names like MSEG.MANDT which means nothing to you but knowing that is the "Client" (MANDT) field may mean something and make it easier to understand in the results for those who use the results of the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case is when you do not have a degenerate simplistic edge case (which, agreed, is not really an edge case here).

Imagine you have joined course TWICE (or more). Been there, seen that. How do you think SQL will distinguish between both "course" instances? course.ID may suddenly not be unique - after all, there are now 2 (or more) course tables joined in in the from clause, with different join conditions.

Exactly. You NAME them in the FROM, then you can use the now unique identifier.

And yes, I have been in situations where I had to join the same table multiple times.

So, as you can see, there is a use case.